# Storing all paths from top left to bottom right in an array of an nxm matrix

Tags: java, arrays

I'm wondering how do I store all paths from top left to bottom right in an array of an n x m matrix. I can only print out the paths I can't really store them in the array. Here is what I have right now

```
public static String printAllPaths(int currX, int currY, String path) throws IOException{


            if(currX == d-1){
                for(int j=currY;j<=d-1;j++){
                    path = path + grid[currX][j];
                }
                //System.out.println(path);
                return path;
            }

            if(currY == d-1){
                for(int i=currX;i<=d-1;i++){
                    path = path + grid[i][currY];
                }
                //System.out.println(path);
                return path;
            }
            path = path + grid[currX][currY];
            printAllPaths(currX+1, currY, path);
            return printAllPaths(currX, currY+1, path);

        }
```

Comment: What is this? A path is a string? What are you talking about IO?

Comment: Your code seems to restrict itself to paths that come closer to the bottom right with each step while your description does not mention any of that, eg a zig-zag-path could be a path from top left to bottom right, but wouldn't be printed by your code. Is that intentional?

Comment: Like giving a 2x2 matrix ABCD a path would be ABD or ACD

Comment: I want to store the resulted strings in an array versus just printing them out